# Is it possible to use cross-validation to estimate the reliability of a specific predictor?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, cross-validation

I have a big dataset with many predictors. I would like to know the quality of these predictors using cross-validation. However, what I am finding is more so methods that test the reliability of the model as a whole.

Is it possible to check the reliability of specific predictors?

Comment: I suggest elastic net instead.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reliability" in this context?  Generally, CV is used to assess predictive value.  (Many researchers use "reliability" as a synonym for *significant*.) You could fit an otherwise identical model w/ & w/o a variable & assess the change in the root mean squared error of the prediction (RMSEP).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the reply. I am indeed using it as a synonym for significant. Basically, my issue is that with so many data points almost every predictor is significant. I would like to separate those that are genuine effects from those that are Type 1 errors. Is the method you suggest the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, cross-validation is used to assess predictive value. From that perspective, you could fit an otherwise identical model with and without a variable and assess the change in the root mean squared error of the prediction (RMSEP).

Many researchers use "reliability" as a synonym for significant.  I gather that is your intention here.  Without intending any disrespect, I think this is a poor usage.   If you haven't done any data snooping / p-hacking, there is no reason to be concerned that many variables are significant at $\alpha = 0.05$ when you have many data.  If you want, you could always use a more stringent alpha to reduce the risk of type I errors when you have many data.

Comment: Thanks very much! This worry over significance is based on a comment from a colleague. Is there a good resource I could cite to say that this isn't an issue?

Comment: @Dave, just an introductory stats book.  That $p<\alpha$ provides $\alpha$-level protection against type-I errors is basically the definition.  If you want to get fancy, maybe Casella & Berger.